# Skipping MEng to go straight to EngD or PhD from BEng

Tags: degree

Generally, the "standard" path of further educational progression in the UK is:

Bachelor's -> Master's -> Doctorate.

However, I've been doing a BEng part-time whilst working full time and as part of my work I also have to do a significant amount of research and have written many academic-style papers (albeit they have only been published internally).

Would it be generally considered acceptable to jump straight from a BEng to a doctorate or are there significant barriers that would be caused by this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in UK, and it isn't my field, but the only real barrier is getting accepted into a program. You may be missing some technical background without an MS, but if you are accepted there will presumably be a way for you to fill in what you need.

Some places the rules may make it impossible for you to even apply, specifying a given degree, but otherwise, the only way to know is to make application and make it as positive as you can. Let the review committee know why you are a great candidate with a high likelihood of success. Of course that is the situation no matter what your formal background.

If an institution doesn't have a path from where you are, it is very likely to be obvious from their online materials.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the field and school, but I went directly from BS to PhD (computer science), and getting the MS was almost considered a consolation prize for people who couldn't finish the PhD.  So I would say start graduate school, and fairly soon you should have an idea about what people at your school think of getting the MS.  If they don't care, I wouldn't either.

Edit: I am US based.

Comment: Was this in the UK?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.  It is becoming more and more the norm to have direct to Ph.D. programs.

I recommend that you get an en passent masters if possible (sometimes you can just fill out a form a couple years through).  I have had employers who were not familiar with academia who wondered about the masters so I list it on my resume even though I never think about it--was in a direct program.

Really, it is no big deal.

Comment: For the UK en passant masters aren't generally a thing. On the other hand the funding model is switching towards an integrated 1 year Masters by research (MRes) + 3 year PhD model, which comes close to the same end.